# Time-delay differential-difference equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, delay-differential-equations

Is it possible that the system 
$$
\begin{cases}
 2\dot{q}(t) + \dot{q}(t-1) + \dot{q}(t+1) = k & \text{if} \hspace{5mm} 0 \leqslant t \leqslant 2 \\
\dot{q}(t) + \dot{q}(t-1) = c & \text{if} \hspace{5mm} 2 \leqslant t \leqslant 3
\end{cases}
$$
has, for suitable constants $k$ and $c$, any $\mathcal{C}^2$ solutions $q:[-1,3] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$  satisfying the conditions $q(t) = - t$ for $t \in [-1, 0]$ and $q(3)=2$ ?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125710/time-delay-differential-equation

Comment: Shouldn't there be constraints for $q(t), t \in [-2,0]$ sice the first equation depends on $t-1$ as well as $t+1$? And why not rewrite it by shifting the time variable one unit to make it causal, i.e. not involving future $t$?

Comment: @oberdada : Can you please write down your idea?

Comment: I haven't seen this kind of problem before, but try this.

Comment: My first comment was slightly misguided (and the second a mistake). Try this instead: $\dot q(t)=-1, t\in[-1,0]$ implies $\dot q(t-1)=-1; t\in[0,1]$. Next, rewrite the first equation as $2\dot q(t) - 1 + \dot q(t+1)=k, t\in[0,1]$. Go on with similar substitutions and see where it takes you.

Comment: Filippo: Can you please write down your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a $C^2$ solution $q$ exists, the function $r$ defined on $[0,3]$ by $r(t)=\dot q(t)+\dot q(t-1)$ is such that $r(t)+r(t+1)=k$ on $[0,2]$ and $r(t)=c$ on $[2,3]$. Hence $k=r(2)+r(3)=2c$ and $r(t)=c$  on $[0,3]$. Since $r(0)=-2$, $c=-2$. Since $\dot q=-1$ on $[-1,0]$, $\dot q=-1$ on $[-1,3]$. Thus $q(t)=-t$ on $[-1,3]$, in particular $q(3)=-3$ and the condition $q(3)=2$ makes $q$ nonexistent.

Comment: Excellent solution, Did..